# How to increase Application Performance when check All record in DatagridView Using checkAll checkbox- VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

```
 For Each row As DataRow In dtList.Rows
            If row("chk") = 0 Then
                row("chk") = 1
            Else
                row("chk") = 0
            End If
  Next
```

This code is not memory efficient. it cannot process 3000 records in DataGrid view. I don't want to do pagination all. please help me fix this issue.

I need the checkbox called chkAll checked change event . Need to loop the dtList's datasource and it should check all the datagridviewCheckboxCell. without processing problem or any delay.

Comment: VBA and VB.NET are not the same language ... please confirm which tag you should be using and then remove the wrong tag (likely remove VBA ... if you are not sure, read the tag wiki)

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: @agaesh kumar Write a routine to add the check to checkbox in the database then refresh or reload the DataGridView